# Data Science conferences?

Tags: community

This is a similar question like the [Statistics Conferences question at CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/statistics-conferences)

What are the most significant annual Data Science conferences?

Rules:

- Include a link to the conference
- Please include links for the talks (be it youtube, the conference site or some other video streaming site)

Comment: Good question - but in its current formulation it isn't conducive to Stack Exchange format as no single answer can be accepted. You might want to consider removing the single conference per answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PyData - talks about Python Data tools
Link: http://pydata.org/events/

There is one PyData conference on the east coast and one on the west coast each year.

---

NIPS - Neural Information Processing Systems (NIPS)
Link: https://nips.cc/

This is one of the hardest / most prestigious academic Machine Learning conferences to get an abstract / poster accepted.

---

The 5th International Workshop on Parallel and Distributed Computing for Large Scale Machine Learning and Big Data Analytics (IEEE IPDPS 2016)
Link: http://parlearning.ecs.fullerton.edu/

This one is also an academic conference with paper submission.

---

Note:
I am not sure if you want academic or nor academic conferences (have conference proceedings / papers associated with the conference).
Some conferences are not about new data science methodologies  but the tools and libraries (e.g. PyData) that implement existing methodologies.
Also, data science is very broad and includes Stat, Machine Learning and data warehousing / mining etc.

Answer (score 4):

Data science is still a domain in fusion, borrowing from neighboring fields.

A recent interesting contender is DSAA, "IEEE International Conference on Data Science and Advanced Analytics". The first edition ([DSAA 2014](http://datamining.it.uts.edu.au/conferences/dsaa14/)) held in Shanghai. The second [DSAA 2015](http://dsaa2015.lip6.fr/) was in Paris, the [DSAA 2016](http://www.idawise.com/News/Dsaa2016.html) edition is announced in Montreal, Canada, on October 17-19, 2016.

[Nuit Blanche](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.fr/2015/11/pcmi-summer-school-mathematics-of-data.html) recently anounced the PCMI Summer school "[The mathematics of data](https://pcmi.ias.edu/program-index/2016)", June-July 2016, Midway, Utah, USA.

Other related conferences and workshops are:

- COLT: [Annual Conference on Learning Theory](http://www.learningtheory.org/) ([COLT 2016](http://www.learningtheory.org/colt2016/), 23-26 June, New-York, USA)

  - videos: [2013 Princeton](http://videolectures.net/colt2013_princeton/), [2014 Barcelona](http://videolectures.net/colt2014_barcelona/), [2015 Paris](http://videolectures.net/colt2015_paris/)
- MMDS: [Workshop on Algorithms for Modern Massive Data Sets](http://mmds-data.org/) ([MMDS 2016](http://mmds-data.org/) edition Berkeley CA 21-24/06/2016)

  - videos: [MMDSworkshop YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/MMDSworkshop), and follow tabs for MMDS 2012 videos, or [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl_tHArJvfnBS-OPQa2jFYhb1ZrCAnyyL)
- ICML: [International Conference on Machine Learning](http://www.machinelearning.org/icml.html) ([ICML 2016](http://icml.cc/2016/), June, New York, USA)

  - videos: [2015 Lille](http://videolectures.net/icml2015_lille/)
- NIPS: [Annual Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems](https://nips.cc/) with NIPS 2016 in Barcelona, 5-10/12/2016

  - videos: NIPS 2015 [tutorials](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2015/Schedule?type=Tutorial), [invited speakers](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2015/Schedule?type=Invited%20Talk), [spotlights](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2015/Schedule?type=Spotlight), [NIPS 2014](https://www.youtube.com/user/NeuralInformationPro)

Answer (score 4):

Just went to this one last week (Open Data Science Conference): http://odsc.com/

It was really enjoyable. Heavy focus on open source technologies. Speakers from high profile (within the community) projects. And they have posted a lot of the videos from it too.

[Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB2SCq-tZtVl2qWH4CjizIb-IrkT_RA1f) of the talk video.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also include the link to the videos in your answer, please?

Comment: They have a YouTube playlist of them here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB2SCq-tZtVl2qWH4CjizIb-IrkT_RA1f

I don't think all of the videos are there, but most are, including some of the workshops.

Comment: Thank You. I have edited the answer for you with the links.

Answer (score 3):

Annual UseR! conference:

- link: [UseR!2015](http://user2015.math.aau.dk/)
- link: [UseR!2016](http://user2016.org/)

Data lead has an annual conference. Last year in the US, this year in Paris:

- http://www.datalead2015.com/index.php

H2O has a conference [H2O world](http://h2oworld.h2o.ai/)

Since Data Science is a very broad subject:

Effective applications of the R language:

- http://www.earl-conference.com/

Strata + Hadoop World:

- http://conferences.oreilly.com/strata

Joint Statistical Meetings:

- https://www.amstat.org/meetings/jsm.cfm

And of course your local [meetups](http://www.meetup.com/)

Answer (score 2):

My favorites ones are Wrangle, Spark Summit and ampcamp.

> 1. Wrangle is a new, single-day, single-track industry event about the principles, practice, and application of Data Science, across multiple data-rich industries. It includes talks from data scientists from companies like Salesforce, Pinterest, Facebook, and Uber about the hardest problems they've faced, and the solutions they found for them.
>      If you're a practicing Data Scientist, Wrangle is for you!
> 2. spark-summit. DATA SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING AT SCALE
> 3. AMP Camps are Big Data training events organized by the UC Berkeley AMPLab about big data analytics, machine learning, and popular open-source software projects produced by the AMPLab. All AMP Camp curricula, and whenever possible videos of instructional talks presented at AMP Camps, are published here and accessible for free.

1. http://www.wrangleconf.com/
2. https://spark-summit.org/
3. http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/

Comment: Our mod, @Seanowen is a speaker at WrangleConf :)

Answer (score 2):

[Strata + Hadoop World](http://conferences.oreilly.com/strata) by O'Reilly

[DataEDGE](https://dataedge.ischool.berkeley.edu/) by Berkeley School of Information. [Link](https://dataedge.ischool.berkeley.edu/2015/video) to the videos.

Answer (score 2):

DataSciCon.Tech

http://datascicon.tech/

This is a 3-day developer-focused conference in Atlanta USA in November/December

Full-day workshops on: 
Data Science for Discovery, Innovation, and Value Creation
Data Science with R Workshop
Introduction to Machine Learning with Python and TensorFlow
Data Analytics with Tableau

Followed by 2 days with deep dive content in 4 tracks on topics such as:
Data Science,
Data Analytics,
Artificial Intelligence,
Machine Learning,
Deep Learning,
Big Data,
Data Visualisation, 
and Deep Learning.

Comment: Please mention your affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

Annual Wolfram Technology Conference.

- [Wolfram Technology Conference 2015](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/)

Technical training, analysis topics on a wide range of industries, software development, curated data, on so on.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have seen that the presentations are [downoadable](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/presentations/).  Any idea where the talk videos are?

Comment: Those are just a fraction of the presentations.  Many more were conducted.  There are tons of videos on the Wolfram Language and the Mathematica platform at http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/

Answer (score 1):

[ACM KDD](http://www.kdd.org/) is the top conference for both industry and academia.

Last time it took place in Sydney. Have a look to [the program and participants](http://www.kdd.org/kdd2015/).

Answer (score 1):

Lots of nice conferences already mentioned by the existing answers. Here are some which I think deserve a place in the top conferences list:

- [MLConf](http://mlconf.com/):  As the name puts: *THE MACHINE LEARNING CONFERENCE*.

Purpose of the conference:

> MLconf gathers communities to discuss the recent research and
>   application of Algorithms, Tools, and Platforms to solve the hard
>   problems that exist within organizing and analyzing massive and noisy
>   data sets.

[Videos link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjeM1xxYb_37bZfyparLS3Q)

- [Baylearn](http://www.baylearn.org/): The Bay Area Machine Learning symposium.

Purpose:

> The BayLearn Symposium aims at gathering scientists in machine
>   learning from the San Francisco Bay Area. While it promotes community
>   building between local researchers from academic and industrial
>   institutions, it also welcomes visitors. This one-day event combines
>   invited talks and posters to foster exchange of ideas.

[Link to videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnf609gsCjoJd_GvQ31SFVA)

- [Fifth Elephant](https://fifthelephant.in):

> The Fifth Elephant is a community-powered conference on the big data
>   ecosystem, covering the technology and its applications in a range of
>   industries.

[Link to videos](https://hasgeek.tv/fifthelephant/)

Comment: Just went to MLConf last week. I was quite disappointed in that each speaker was only given 20 min. each to speak. So, the talks were very high-level and not deep technical talks. Quite honestly a lot of local meetups are quite good and they tend to have an interesting variety of topics.

Comment: @init-random That should be frustrating as an attendee.  I only watched Xavier(from Quora)'s talk.

Answer (score 1):

[PASS Analytics](http://passbaconference.com/2016/Home.aspx) - The Professional Association for SQL Server has an analytics focused conference. While some of the conference tracks may not be for highly qualified data scientists, many are specifically relevant as Microsoft continues to support Hadoop and integrates R into SQL Server among many other things.

> Whether you’re just starting out in the data analytics field, are a
>   data pro who sees the value in expanding your skillset, or are a
>   seasoned business analytics pro, the PASS Business Analytics
>   Conference is the place to be.

Answer (score 1):

Startup.ml conference has had a couple good conferences. The talks are done by experts in the field and I found more technical and practical than other conferences.

http://conf.startup.ml

Answer (score 1):

*Disclosure*: This message is posted by The Data Science Conference® team.

If the idea of a no-sponsor, no-vendor, no-recruiter data science conference is appealing to you, The Data Science Conference® might be a good option.

Link: http://www.thedatascienceconference.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at :

http://www.kdnuggets.com/meetings/

It has a list of conferences and meetings of Data Science split by each month.