# How can one can aim for a career in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, beginner, career

I'm interested in various machine learning methods and wonder how can I aim for a career in the field.
What are most basic skills to have?

I mean the matters strictly connected to the machine learning - not programming or libraries.

Comment: I'm sorry I need to vote it close as opinion-based  :(

Can you edit it and be a bit more specific?

Comment: @Dawny33 I mean the matters strictly connected to the machine learning - not programming or libraries. I just don't know how to put it into words. :(

Comment: @Luke The problem is that the question "what are the most basic skills" are based on personal opinion. People might disagree on the answer; there is not a single right answer. This kind of question is probably more suitable on reddit.com

Comment: @moose I wanted to ask for the essential knowledge. Feel free to edit my question.

Comment: @Luke I understand what you asked and I've answered to that question. If you think I understood it wrong, you have to clarify. If I got it right, then this is opinion based. (I'm not saying this is a bad question; I only say that it is not suitable for the StackExchange format).

Answer (score 4):

Machine Learning is a really big field. Depending on what exactly you want to do, there might be huge differences.

Having said that, the following skills are helpful:

- Programming, especially Python / C++
- Frameworks like [TensorFlow](http://tensorflow.org), [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), [Torch](http://torch.ch/), ...
- Algorithms like neural networks (especially gradient descent), SVM, decision trees, clustering algorithms, Q-Learning, ...
- Mathematics (e.g. probability theory / statistics, linear algebra, analysis for calculating gradients

Knowing how to program the GPU directly (CUDA) is probably not always necessary, but certainly a big bonus.

In case you're interested what you learn at KIT (Karlsruhe, Germany) in an introductory machine learning course, see [my blog post for exam preparation](http://martin-thoma.com/machine-learning-1-course/) (I'm sorry, it is mostly in German).

### Online Courses

There are lots of online material for machine learning. For example an [Coursera ML course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning)

Answer (score 2):

I have already answered similar questions [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9439/11097) and [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/8965/11097)

So, that would help you get an idea of how you need to design your own learning path.

The reason why I said that this question is opinion-based is:

> Data Science is a huge domain in itself, and attaining complete
>   knowledge of everything in it, is close to impossible.
>
> So, if I am interested in pursuing the concept of Neural Networks
>   alone, and subsequently Deep Learning; then my learning path would be
>   completely different to someone who wants to learn a different concept like time series.
>
> And so does that of someone who wants to learn some other concept. The
>   concepts might be intertwined, but something which I absolutely
>   require in my learning path might not be necessary to someone else's.

So, those above resources are a rough guide to get started.

In addition to that, here is a list of [conferences](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8941/11097) and [podcasts](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9000/11097) of Data Science, which help you with your learning.

And also keep an eye on the [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag here.

Additional reading:

[Applying machine learning in a real world example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/174140/84191)
[A really good neural networks and deep learning book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/)